# Variance of Completely Pooled Regression Estimator on Two Different Distributions

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I know that this question seems somewhat contrived, but I'm essentially trying to weigh the tradeoffs of completely pooling regression estimators when I have data from two "environments" vs. estimating regression estimators separately for each environment.

Specifically, assume that we have observations

\begin{equation*}
y_{1}, ..., y_{n}, y_{n+1}, ..., y_{n+m}
\end{equation*}

where the first $n$ observations are from environment 0 and the final $m$ observations are from environment 1. We assume each $y_{i}$ from environment 0 is drawn independently as

\begin{equation*}
y_{i} \sim N(\beta_{0}^{(0)} + \beta_{1}^{(0)}x_{i}, \sigma_{(0)}^{2})
\end{equation*}

and each $y_{i}$ from environment 1 is drawn independently as

\begin{equation*}
y_{i} \sim N(\beta_{0}^{(1)} + \beta_{1}^{(1)}x_{i}, \sigma_{(1)}^{2}),
\end{equation*}

where $x_{i}$ is a 1-dimensional covariate for the $i^{th}$ individual.

Now, I'd like to calculate the mean squared error of estimating both $\beta_{1}^{(0)}$ and $\beta_{1}^{(1)}$ by running one regression with all $n+m$ observations.

From computational experiments as well as my intuition, I believe that the variance of this estimator should depend on $(\beta_{1}^{(0)} - \beta_{1}^{(1)})^{2}$. However, I'm having a hard time deriving this. Here's how I start (where I call the combined estimator $\beta_{1}^{(c)}$):

\begin{align*}
Var\Big[\hat{\beta}_{1}^{(c)}\Big] &= Var\Bigg[\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})(y_{i} - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}}\Bigg]\\
&= Var\Bigg[ \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})y_{i} - \bar{y}\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}} \Bigg]\\
&= Var\Bigg[ \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})y_{i}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}} \Bigg] \textrm{ (since $\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x}) = 0$)}\\
&= \frac{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}Var[y_{i}] + \sum_{i = n + 1}^{n + m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}Var[y_{i}] }{\Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}\Big)^{2}} \textrm{ (since each $y_{i}$ is generated independently)}\\
&= \frac{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}\sigma_{(0)}^{2} + \sum_{i = n + 1}^{n + m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}\sigma_{(1)}^{2} }{\Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n+m}(x_{i} - \bar{x})^{2}\Big)^{2}}\\
\end{align*}

which does not depend on the difference in effect size between the environments.

Below is a computational simulation (which takes less than a minute on my machine) I run which seems to show that the variance does in fact depend on the difference in means.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
num_sims <- 1000
beta_vec <- c(0:10)
sim_var_vec <- c()

for (beta in beta_vec) {
  
  beta_est_vec <- numeric(num_sims)
  
  for (i in c(1:num_sims)) {
    
    x_env0 <- rnorm(n)
    x_env1 <- rnorm(n)
    
    y_env0 <- rnorm(n) # simulate beta in environment 0 as 0
    y_env1 <- beta * x_env1 + rnorm(n)
    
    sim_df <- data.frame(x = c(x_env0, x_env1), y = c(y_env0, y_env1))
    
    lm_comb <- lm(y ~ x, data = sim_df)
    beta_est <- coef(summary(lm_comb))['x', 'Estimate']
    beta_est_vec[i] <- beta_est
    
  }
  
  sim_var_vec <- c(sim_var_vec, var(beta_est_vec))
  
}

plot(beta_vec, sim_var_vec)
```

If you examine the plot, it looks like there is a quadratic relationship between beta and the variance of the combined estimator.

So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: could you upload the plot?

Comment: the reason involves you generating the covariates $x$ during each pass of the simulation. Pull `x_env0 <- rnorm(n); x_env1 <- rnorm(n)` outside of the `for` loops and look at the output. This makes the simulation fix the covariates, as you have done in your calculation. How would you update your calculation to take into account your original placement of the coviarate generatino?